# How to change the hyperlink text programmatically using conditionals?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this template `Field` in my `aspx` page:

```
<<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<%--FGRVesselID query  string of crystal report--%>
<asp:Hyperlink ID="fgr" runat="server" Target ="_blank" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("v_id", "~/operator/printFGR.aspx?FGRVesselID={0}") %>' Text ="FGR" font-underline="false" ForeColor="blue" CssClass="links"></asp:Hyperlink>
</Itemtemplate>
<HeaderStyle CssClass ="tblheader2" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The *hyperlink text* of that template field should change depending on the condition in the code.

Here's the code behind:

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
   If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
      Dim fgr As HyperLink = DirectCast(GridView1.FindControl("fgr"), HyperLink)
      If e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Catcher" Then
        e.Row.Cells(9).Enabled = True
      Else                       
        fgr.Text = "N/A"
      End If
   End If
 End Sub
```

I have to change the hyperlink text to "N/A" if cell(9) is not equal to "Catcher" but i   got an error of "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
    How will I able to change the hyperlink text if the condition above is not met?

Answer (score 0):

To get the hyperlink you need to find the control within the current row, not within the whole gridview as below.

```
Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
   If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
      Dim fgr As HyperLink = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("fgr"), HyperLink)
      If e.Row.Cells(2).Text = "Catcher" Then
        e.Row.Cells(9).Enabled = True
      Else                       
        fgr.Text = "N/A"
      End If
   End If
 End Sub
```